# How to use XML annotations such as "XMLRoot" to parse schema like <field key="AA" id="BB">CC</field> in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

In order to parse

```
<field key="AA" code="BB">CC</field>
```

I suppose it should be something like

```
[XmlRoot("field")]
public Field 
{
   // Get AA
   [XmlAttribute("key")]
   string key;

   // Get BB
   [XmlAttribute("id")]
   string id;

}
```

Then how to get CC? I have looked at many places, but there are no solutions??

Answer (score 2):

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("field")]
[XmlElement()]
public Field 
{
   // Get AA
   [XmlAttribute("key")]
   string key;

   // Get BB
   [XmlAttribute("id")]
   string id;

   string cc;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But which .net version are you using? It seems I could not find XmlValue in 3.5 sp1.

Comment: Arg, don't know what I was thinking.  Edit comming.